# Has the United States only ratified 5 of 18 international treaties on human rights?

Tags: united-states, politics, law

A recent [opinion piece in the English edition of Le Monde Diplomatique](https://mondediplo.com/2022/03/02ukraine-sanctions) makes passing reference to the idea that the United States "has ratified only five of the 18 international human rights treaties."

That seems a little low, and possibly outdated. Does anyone know of a more official source that can confirm this?

Comment: Questions need to have a notable claim and source that claim properly in order to be considered on topic. Saying you raid something isn't enough and you need to link to the sources so that others can verify the claim. In addition some basic research should be done and it appears that the answer was easily findable as you answered your own question in about 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I've added a link.

Comment: Note that this sounds worse than it is because signing treaties is not as important as actually complying with them. For example, despite signing treaties against torture, they are still actively using it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guantanamo_Bay_detention_camp & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_black_sites

Comment: @Gantendo Sounds worse than it is? Doesn't your example show exactly the opposite? It is *even worse than it sounds* since despite signing and ratifying the convention against torture they are actively using it.

Comment: If a country promises to stop doing something, and then continues to do it, it makes their promise worthless and I wouldn't believe in (or care about) any future promises.

Comment: @Gantendo Well, it depends on the premises. You could say that a country that ratifies a treaty and still violates it is not credible. OTOH, you could also say that its general political compass is pointed toward respecting the treaty, but actual enforcement is flimsy. It strongly depends on the specifics of the violations (numbers, severity, etc).

Comment: @Gantendo **However**, a country that doesn't ratifies a treaty is telling the world something like "If I ratify the treaty, I know I will violate it. Therefore I don't do it because I want my hands free". In general I find this latter attitude much more disturbing when the treaty concerns human rights or other ethically sensitive matters.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine "I have more respect for a man who lets me know where he stands, even if he's wrong, than the one who comes up like an angel and is nothing but a devil." -- Malcolm X

Comment: @Gantendo I largely agree. However, for good or bad, countries don't behave or "think" like individuals (not even when led by dictators).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The claim is true.

The [UN Treaty Body Database](https://tbinternet.ohchr.org/_layouts/15/TreatyBodyExternal/Treaty.aspx?CountryID=187&Lang=EN) has a drop-down selection for United States of America.
This shows that USA has signed 9 treaties, but ratified only 5 of them.

| Treaty | Signature Date | Ratification Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAT - Convention against Torture and Other Cruel Inhuman or Degrading Treatment or Punishment | 18 Apr 1988 | 21 Oct 1994 |
| CAT-OP - Optional Protocol of the Convention against Torture |  |  |
| CCPR - International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights | 05 Oct 1977 | 08 Jun 1992 |
| CCPR-OP2-DP - Second Optional Protocol to the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights aiming to the abolition of the death penalty |  |  |
| CED - Convention for the Protection of All Persons from Enforced Disappearance |  |  |
| CED, Art.32 - Interstate communication procedure under the International Convention for the Protection of All Persons from Enforced Disappearance |  |  |
| CEDAW - Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Discrimination against Women | 17 Jul 1980 |  |
| CERD - International Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination | 28 Sep 1966 | 21 Oct 1994 |
| CESCR - International Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights | 05 Oct 1977 |  |
| CMW - International Convention on the Protection of the Rights of All Migrant Workers and Members of Their Families |  |  |
| CRC - Convention on the Rights of the Child | 16 Feb 1995 |  |
| CRC-OP-AC - Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of the Child on the involvement of children in armed conflict | 05 Jul 2000 | 23 Dec 2002 |
| CRC-OP-SC - Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of the Child on the sale of children child prostitution and child pornography | 05 Jul 2000 | 23 Dec 2002 |
| CRPD - Convention on the Rights of Persons with Disabilities | 30 Jul 2009 |  |

The website is published by The UN Human Rights Office.

Comment: The claim is that the U.S. has ratified only 5 of **18** treaties.  The data table presented indicates that the U.S. has ratified only 5 of the **14** treaties listed.  If that treaty list is accepted as the appropriate one against which to check the claim, then the claim is only partly true.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sounds like Le Monde is using a more general definition of human rights treaties than the UN's list. But then we need to know what the other 4 are, so we can confirm whether the US ratified any.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the UN states there are **9** 'core treaties' [here](https://www.ohchr.org/en/core-international-human-rights-instruments-and-their-monitoring-bodies) but lists 18 treaties. IDK the distinctinctions between treaties, core treaties, sub-treaties etc., why they list some and not others. I showed what UN says have been ratified. If USA has *signed* 9 treaties, perhaps they are the 'core treaties'.

Comment: @WeatherVane Patrick's answer tells you where to find the "missing" four.

Comment: Perhaps that's the right list, @WeatherVane.  At a quick glance, it appears to include almost all the items from the list in this answer, plus some addditional "optional protocols".  It does not distinguish CED Article 32 as separate from CED.  I'd be willing to accept the claim in question to be true, subject to an understanding of which treaties we're talking about, but it does seem slightly disingenuous to give the optional protocols the same weight as the core treaties, as the claim seems to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if you mean disingenuous of *Le Monde* then I thought so too; a "how bad is that" story will always compare the smallest it can find with the largest. Although the map linked by [Patrick's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/53330/52183) does show that many countries have ratified all 18 treaties. Well done for counting, I knew I had only listed 14 and waited to see the reaction.

Comment: Yes, I mean of *Le Monde*.

Comment: Funny that an anti-torture treaty is there when the US is infamous for mass torture. To quote President Obama: ["We tortured some folks"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YBinnWqABQ) (02:10); no senior US official was tried for this IIANM.

Answer (score 26):

The [currently accepted answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/53331/4773) includes a table that states the United States has ratified 5 of **14** (not 18) international human rights treaties.  This answer is intended to provide some context on the 14 versus 18 aspect of the question.

The [Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_the_United_Nations_High_Commissioner_for_Human_Rights) (OHCHR) considers there to be **9** *core* international human rights instruments:

1. Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Racial Discrimination (ICERD, 1965)
2. International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights (ICCPR, 1966)
3. International Covenant on Economic, Social, and Cultural Rights (ICESCR, 1966)
4. Convention on the Elimination of All Forms of Discrimination Against Women (CEDAW, 1979)
5. Convention against Torture and Other Cruel, Inhuman or Degrading Treatment or Punishment (CAT, 1984)
6. Convention on the Rights of the Child (CRC, 1989)
7. International Convention on the Protection of the Rights of All Migrant Workers and Members of Their Families (ICMW, 1990)
8. International Convention for the Protection of All Persons from Enforced Disappearance (CPED, 2006)
9. Convention on the Rights of Persons with Disabilities (CRPD, 2006)

(The United States has signed 7 and ratified 3 of these 9 core treaties.)

In addition, there are 9 *optional protocols* associated with these instruments:

10. Optional Protocol to the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights (ICCPR-OP1, 1966)
11. Second Optional Protocol to the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights, aiming at the abolition of the death penalty (ICCPR-OP2, 1989)
12. Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Elimination of Discrimination against Women (OP-CEDAW, 1999)
13. Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of the Child on the involvement of children in armed conflict (OP-CRC-AC, 2000)
14. Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of the Child on the sale of children, child prostitution and child pornography (OP-CRC-SC, 2000)
15. Optional Protocol to the Convention against Torture and Other Cruel, Inhuman or Degrading Treatment or Punishment (OP-CAT, 2002)
16. Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of Persons with Disabilities (OP-CRPD, 2006)
17. Optional Protocol to the Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights (ICESCR-OP, 2008)
18. Optional Protocol to the Convention on the Rights of the Child on a communications procedure (OP-CRC-IC, 2014)

(The United States has signed 2 and ratified 2 of these optional protocols.)

These 9+9=18 instruments are presumably "the 18 international human rights treaties" referenced in the question.

The 14 treaties mentioned elsewhere include the 9 core treaties, 4 of the optional protocols, and 1 more not included above:

19. Interstate communication procedure under the International Convention for the Protection of All Persons from Enforced Disappearance (CED Art.32, 2010)

Some other lists online also include instruments such as [HURIDOCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HURIDOCS), [OMCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMCT), [ICSPCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_International_Convention_on_the_Suppression_and_Punishment_of_the_Crime_of_Apartheid), [CRSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees), [Convention on the Reduction of Statelessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_on_the_Reduction_of_Statelessness), [CPPCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocide_Convention), and [ILO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_and_Tribal_Peoples_Convention,_1989).

Comment: Some ideas why the US didnt sign the optional treaties?

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees I guess the reasons will vary, but on some they did not sign the underlying treaty in the first place, some like the one on abolition of the death penalty are kind of obvious and I think several of the others establish some form of international jurisdiction regarding the subject, something which US politics only seems to believe in if it is sure that they will be winning all their cases.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees: A full answer would be out of scope here (ask on Politics.SE), but in short, [the US likes its sovereignty and distrusts the UN](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/932/7303).

Answer (score 9):

Found it. According to the UN Office of the High Commissioner, the number is indeed 5.

https://indicators.ohchr.org/

Of the "orange" countries I hovered over on the map, only two -- Myanmar and Iran -- were close to being that low, with 6 ratified human rights treaties per country.

====

EDIT #1: Malaysia also has 5.

EDIT #2: There's also a "red" category, but no sizeable countries appear to be in it.

Comment: The linked page is dated 2014 at the bottom.

Comment: Good catch. If anyone has a more recent source, I'll be much obliged.

Comment: It's not exactly a good look when *North Korea* has ratified more human rights treaties (6) than a given country.

Comment: @WeatherVane The copyright date likely tells little about the data itself, it's a generic footer for the whole website (and nobody probably considered it important enough to keep bumping it every year). The "Metadata" PDF on the page lists 02 August 2020 as the "Last updated" date, which might be more relevant. Anyway, as your answer shows, nothing has really changed wrt the US since 2014.

Comment: The "orange" countries are those with "5-9" treaties signed. There is a red category with "4 or fewer" treaties signed. Bhutan and some pacific islands are in it.

Comment: @TooTea Technically, if the only alteration made to a document is updating information in a table, the new document is not separately copyrightable from the original, since it is not distinct in its copyrightable aspects, so it would be incorrect to indicate a new copyright date.

Comment: @Obie2.0 actually, its the opposite. North Korea signing "human rights" documents goes to show that these treaties are toothless and it doesn't matter who did or did not sign them.